# Почему ставится запятая перед союзом И?

Tags: пунктуация

Лишь только Маргарита коснулась влажной травы, музыка под вербами ударила сильнее, и веселее взлетел сноп искр из костра.

**У Лопатина:** Когда взошло солнце, роса высохла и трава позеленела (нет запятой при наличии общей придаточной части).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Лишь только Маргарита коснулась влажной травы, музыка под вербами
>   ударила сильнее, и веселее взлетел сноп искр из костра.

Видимо, помимо одновременности событий, Булгаков видел здесь и причинно-следственные связи, придавая им большее значение: Маргарита коснулась травы, поэтому музыка ударила сильнее, а ударила музыка - сноп искр веселее взлетел. Таким образом, придаточное не является общим для двух самостоятельных.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Я не знаю, знаком ли был Булгаков с таким правилом, но по структуре достаточно распространенного предложения  (а может быть, и по семантике текста) здесь чувствуется пауза, которую хочется обозначить запятой. Но как быть с формальным правилом, особенно на экзамене, если не поставишь запятую? (Я это предложение взяла из проверочного учебного текста).

Comment: Sibylla,а в учебнике с запятой или без?

Comment: Серж,  это проверочный тест на сайте, где надо расставить запятые, в ответах запятая стоит.

Comment: Sibylla, в интернете я видел это предложение и без запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, автор первых строк не руководствовался правилом об общей придаточной части, а поставил запятую по общему правилу.

Либо — хоть я в это не верю — запятая поясняет нам, что автор совсем не хотел связывать сноп искр от костра с моментом, когда Маргарита коснулась травы. (Но это уж совсем маловероятно: автор просто не стал бы тогда вписывать это в одно предложение.)

Примечание: возможно, запятую поставил не автор, а корректор издательства (если Ваши цитаты взяты из книг).

Comment: В современных правилах (ПАС под ред. Лопатина) это требование является обязательным, если придаточное относится к обеим частям  сложного предложения. Или Вы хотите сказать, что сохранена авторская пунктуация (Первый полный вариант «Мастера и Маргариты» была завершен в 1934 году, последний — в 1938-м. Первый полный текст книги вышел отдельным изданием в 1967 г.).

Comment: Авторы — тоже люди, пусть даже и писатели. Их главная задача не показать читателям, как они в совершенстве владеют языком, а донести до них свой замысел. Не все авторы полностью грамотны. (Чёрт возьми, далеко не все вообще грамотны...)

Comment: Первые академические правила письма  были ведены в 1956 году, автор не был с ними знаком,  но ведь  старые тексты  должны как-то корректироваться. Или нет?

Comment: Другой вариант: текст включается в современные диктанты. Захотел человек проверить свою грамотность,  написал диктант, не стал ставить запятую, а запятая в тексте есть, вот и ошибка.

Comment: Целиком на совести составителей диктанта. По-моему, проверять знание школьниками _современного_ языка _старыми_ текстами как-то неразумно.

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствие запятой скорее всего можно объяснить тем, что в вашем примере придаточная часть относится только к одной из частей сложносочиненного предложения.
Ср.у Лопатина: **Когда я крепко двинул лыжи под гору, облако холодной снежной пыли взвилось мне навстречу, и по всему девственно-белому, пушистому косогору правильно и красиво прорезались два параллельных следа;**

Comment: Серж, но у Булгакова, кажется, однозначно описывается ситуация:  действия  в двух последних предложениях происходят одновременно, а сам момент времени обозначен в первом предложении.